# How can I query WMI to know the name of the user that started a service?

Tags: service, wmi

I used several WMI queries in `wbemtest` to attempt finding out which user started a particular service. The ones that got me "this far" are presented here.
I know that if I query the win32_service object like:

```
select * from win32_service where name like '%SERVICENAME%'
```

I obtain only one result (the service I'm looking for), then I double click it to browse the service properties, and found out there's a property called "**StartName**" which shows the name of the user that started it (that's what I want).

Now, the problem begins when I do:

```
 select StartName from win32_service where name like '%SERVICENAME%'
```

I get `Win32_Service = <no key>`:

[image: wbemtest]

Even without the `where` clause it shows the same.

What am I missing to make it work?

Comment: Works fine for me: `select StartName from win32_service where name like '%winmgmt%'` returns a service with `StartName` = `localSystem`. What OS are you using? Can you post a complete code example that illustrates the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks Helen, I'm using wbemtest.exe on Windows 8.1x64, though I'm not sure that would it have to behave so differently.
I'll try this in my Hyper-V Windows7x64 VM as well today to see if it works there.
http://imageshack.com/a/img4/3029/19qs.jpg

Comment: No luck, it shows the same result. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a display thing. Your query works, and if you double-click the result, you'll see the service's `StartName`:

[image: wbemtest]

I guess it happens because you don't `SELECT` the key property - `Name`. If you add `Name` to your query, you'll see `Win32_Service.Name=`*`name`* in the results.

[image: wbemtest]

By the way, in code you'll get both the `SELECT`ed properties and key properties whether or not you query the key properties:

```vbs
' VBScript example
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT StartName FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name LIKE '%winmgmt%'",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name ' <-- Name is there, even though we didn't query it
    Wscript.Echo "StartName: " & objItem.StartName
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a code for C# that actually Works.

```
    public Service GetServiceDetails(string serviceName)
    {
      using (var managementBaseObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '{0}'", serviceName))).Get())
      {
        ManagementObject mo = managementBaseObject.Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (mo == null) return null;

        var service = new Service
        {
          AcceptPause = mo["AcceptPause"] != null && (bool) mo["AcceptPause"],
          AcceptStop = mo["AcceptStop"] != null && (bool)mo["AcceptStop"],
          Caption =  mo["Caption"] != null ? mo["Caption"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          Description =  mo["Description"] != null ? mo["Description"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          DisplayName = mo["DisplayName"] != null ? mo["DisplayName"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          Name = mo["Name"] != null ? mo["Name"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          PathName = mo["PathName"] != null ? mo["PathName"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          ProcessId = mo["ProcessId"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessId"]) : 0,
          ServiceType = mo["ServiceType"] != null ? mo["ServiceType"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          Started = mo["Started"] != null && (bool)mo["Started"],
          StartMode = mo["StartMode"] != null ? mo["StartMode"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          StartName = mo["StartName"] != null ? mo["StartName"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          State = mo["State"] != null ? mo["State"].ToString() : string.Empty,
          Status = mo["Status"] != null ? mo["Status"].ToString() : string.Empty,
        };
        return service;
      }
    }
```